# How can I add this image plugin, on a new clean/new texteditor?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

When I want to add a texteditor `admin/config/content/formats`
4 editors; basic,restricted,full and plain are pre installed.

The basic.HTML CKEditor is with image plugin installed
[image]

When I create a new text format, the image plugin is not enabled and there is no obvious way to open it. How do I get the image plugin when configuring a new text format?

Comment: What is the question? This isn't clear enough.

Comment: The red box indicaties a basic.html CKEDITOR, how to create these image settings in a New editor?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by activating the image plugin for CKEditor.

Drag the following icon from the available icons to the active toolbar:

[image]

Comment: When creating a new format you first need to drag the icon off, and then back on. The CKEditor plugin settings do not display by default even though the image plugin is in the Active toolbar. This seems like a bug in drupal core 8.2.x.